# Difference between AmazonS3 vs S3Client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to access a pdf stored in s3 bucket .
I have bucket name and arn. After going through lot of example I did not understand difference between two services S3Client and AmazonS3 .

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Region.US_EAST_1)
                .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                .build();

S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder().region(Region.US_EAST_1).build();
```

Not getting what to use?

Answer (score 7):

**AmazonS3** is Java Version 1 and **S3Client** is Java version 2. It is strongly recommended that moving forward, you use Java Version 2. To learn about the difference between V1 and V2, read this document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/migration-guide/whats-different.html